# try-catch block not catching the Exception

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm using a try-catch block to identify the lack of some data in a database. Before I started using the while to check user input it was doing fine but now the try-catch block wont be executed (the while is inside the try-catch).
The exception I'm trying to catch is the InvalidOperationException thrown by the OleDbDataReader when the query returns nothing.

```
try
{
    string _cmd = "SELECT razao_social FROM tblImobiliarias WHERE cnpj ='" + ValorConsulta.Text + "'";
    string conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=\\\\10.7.41.153\\Apoio\\Davi_Database\\Base_Imo.accdb";
    OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(conn);
    OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(_cmd, Connection);
    Connection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int _resMatriz = 0;
        DialogResult result;
        result = MessageBox.Show(
              "Encontrado imobiliária: " 
            + reader[_resMatriz] 
            + ".\nEstá correto?", "Pesquisa", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        _resMatriz++;
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CarregaImo()");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        } 
    }
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(
        "O CNPJ " 
        + ValorConsulta.Text 
        + " não foi localizado no sistema.\nOs dados não podem ter pontuação. Tente novamente",
        "Pesquisa", 
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Comment: Don't do that.  You should only have a `catch` block if you can actually handle the exception, which you aren't.  At the very least, use `throw;`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of your code. Run the program. Step through the code line by line with F10. Hover the mouse over every variable you see, or view their values in the watch window. If you do this, you will find the cause of your problem.

Comment: Not an answer but: I'd also advise against constructing a query that way because it's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Consider changing that to use parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: The idea is to get the InvalidOperationException if the reader returns null. If it does that, the while wont execute. Will it?

Comment: If there are no records then the while loop is never executed (and no exception is thrown by NET or by your code) And if the database field is null then the reader[index] returns DbNull.Value that is convertible to a string so, again no exception is thrown

Comment: I dont really get it. If my _cmd string is "SELECT * FROM tblImobiliarias WHERE cnpj = '8957235981273759'" wich obviously will return nothing the exception is thrown. If it is, then the catch will execute but in this case the exception it's not being thrown.

Comment: Again. if the call to ExecuteReader doesn't produce records it still returns a valid datareader. When you call reader.Read it returns false and your while is not executed, No exception is thrown for this. Why don't you try to remove the try/catch and look exactly if you get any exception? And if you get one what is it exactly and on which line?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your intentions, but it appears you're resetting `resMaritz` each time through the loop. You then increment it after using it as an index for `reader`. It will always be 0 the way you have it, and I don't know why you were incrementing it or what your intentions with reader in this case...

Comment: I see. The exception it's only thrown if there is bad SQL syntax. `if (reader[0] == null) { } else { }` seems to do just fine.

Comment: Is it possible you get the exception when you use `8957235981273759` because that's a long and the actual field is an `int` as opposed to a `bigint`? The value you supplied is well beyond the maximum for an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against using an `Exception` for normal application logic. If your reader has no results, you can use the 'HasRows` property like so:

```
OleDbDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.HasRows)
{
    // Do what you need if there are rows
}
else // Instead of an exception handler
{
    MessageBox.Show("O CNPJ " + ValorConsulta.Text + " não foi localizado no sistema.\nOs dados não podem ter pontuação. Tente novamente", "Pesquisa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    throw new InvalidOperationException(); // If you must throw the exception
}
```